# Remove commits with obsolete patches

Tags: git, github, merge, patch

On a feature branch it is likely to happen from time to time that you write some code, commit it and later change parts of it again in a later commit.
For a reviewer of that feature branch it is only necessary to know the end result, not how you got there.
Hence my question:
Is there a way to have git automatically merge these commits with later obsolete changes so that they won’t clutter commit history?

Comment: Are you asking about squashing all commits into a single commit or are you asking how to do `git diff master...feature`? Most code review tools (GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket) show the full diff by default anyway.

Comment: @knittl, I know I can squash, but then all other commits will be squashed too. Plus I don’t want to do it manually. I’m looking for a way to let git only sort out the commits that introduce changes that are made obsolete by successional commits. Or even just removes these changes. I figured there must be some way using smart rebasing or the like…

Comment: I'm gonna need an example. For ten commits on a branch you could call everything but the last commit “obsolete changes”. That sounds like more of a subjective judgement which (if that is true) cannot be automated. But if you want help with fixing up previous commits you can look into the third party git-absorb(1).

Comment: Generally squashing the commits is done at the time when a pull request is merged. PRs aren't a part of git though, that's added on top in things like Github.  Like knittl said, you generally look at the diff for review, not the individual commits.